# How to fade in on click using the following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to have my current code fade in for each transitioning image. I'm not sure how to integrate fadeIn in my code because when I did that it would then reveal the images when I just want one image shown at a time.

HTML:

```
 <div>
  <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/BF116-11KM.jpg" class="is-selected" />
  <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/BF89-11K.jpg" />
  <img src="https://cdn.atwilltech.com/flowerdatabase/s/sweetly-scented-bouquet-of-flowers-VA02810.425.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  display: none;
}

.is-selected {
  display: inline;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("img").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass();
  if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
    $(":first-child").addClass("is-selected");
  } else {
    $(this).next().addClass("is-selected");
  }
});
```

Here it is on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmrfdb2a/20/

I am basically trying to make a slideshow with the images fading in as they transition. If anyone can lead me in the right direction that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
img {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
}

.is-selected {
   visibility: visible;
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmrfdb2a/34/)